# 404 on pretty permalinks when serving via HTTPS

Tags: permalinks, 404-error, https

I deployed my wordpress site in Google Cloud Compute Engine. To enable SSL I followed the the steps outlined here https://www.onepagezen.com/free-ssl-certificate-wordpress-google-cloud-click-to-deploy

1. Install Certbot Client
2. Generate Certificates
3. Configure the Certificates
4. Enable HTTPS Redirect
5. Restart Apache Server
6. Update WordPress URLs
7. Configure SSL Auto-Renewal

Edit `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf`

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        <Directory /var/www/html>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            Require all granted
        </Directory> 
    ...
```

and `/etc/apache2/sites-available/wordpress.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  ServerName mydomain.com
  ServerAlias mydomain.com
  Redirect permanent / https..mydomain.com

  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
  </Directory>

  <Directory /var/www/html/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
  <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
  # alert, emerg.
  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

After setting everything up, I run:

```
sudo a2ensite default-ssl
sudo a2enmod ssl
sudo service apache2 restart
```

SSL works fine for the backend and the landing page. However for all other pages I get a 404. When I switch form custom permalinks to simple permalinks the pages are accessible again. Any ideas what might be causing the problem?

Comment: did you adjust wp's standard htaccess file?

Comment: @Pat_Morita as I understand correctly, the htaccess file gets adjusted automatically by changing the permalink settings in wordpress. I actually tested it and the htaccess file gets overwritten when I change the settings.

Comment: Is `Redirect permanent / https..mydomain.com` actually how it is or is this shorthand intended to communicate that all requests are port 80 should be redirected to 443?

Comment: @Artjom Zabelin - Do you have some kind of a load balancer active?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty common problem. Unfortunately there are dozens of possible causes, which may be on the server level as well as the WordPress level. Therefore, it is impossible to pinpoint a solution for you.

One thing you know is that the server settings you mention are working correctly at least in part, in the sense that they read the WordPress `.htaccess` file, because that's where the redirects for pretty permalinks are stored. Still, there might be trouble if somewhere down the track there is a redirect to `http`, which the server might then refuse to serve ([this seems to be a problem with Google's service](https://googlecloudplatform.uservoice.com/forums/302616-load-balancing/suggestions/31951531-allow-http-to-redirect-to-https-automatically)).

Any server related trouble is off topic here, but there are a couple of things on the WordPress level you could try:

- Disable all plugins (except your SSL-plugin) and resave the permalinks. This makes sure no plugins are redirecting to http
- Make sure there are no `.htaccess` files in subdirectories inadvertently redirecting to http.
- Add `$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';` to your `config.php` file to tell WordPress that is is supposed to serve all pages with `https`. Sometimes the server setup is so complex WordPress cannot determine this itself.
- Alternatively, force your whole domain to https with these lines in `.htaccess`:

  `RewriteEngine On`

  `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on`

  `RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a load balancer, try to add following line in wp-config.php

```
$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

Comment: @Artyom Zabelin did this helped you?